# How to add any language[punjabi] in Libre office 3

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I'm using Ubuntu from last 2 years. Today there is urgency to write a letter in **Punjabi language**[named as Lohit Punjabi] in Libre office. But when I have tried to write in Punjabi language, by default it writes in English. Any suggestion regarding, how I am able to write a letter in the language[punjabi] font in Libre office. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to add the Punjabi language to the list of keyboard layout languages, so that you can switch back and forth between your system's default language and Punjabi by clicking on the language switcher icon in the system notification area next to the system clock. Click *System Settings* (in the Launcher) -> *Keyboard Layout* and you will see the **Keyboard Layout** window shown below. In 14.04 and later the navigation shown below has been  changed to System Settings -> *Text Entry*.

[image]

Click on the **+** button in the lower left-hand corner of the Keyboard Layout window to open the **Choose a Layout** window shown below:

[image]

Select your new keyboard layout language from the list and click **Add** to add Punjabi to your keyboard layout languages.

The part of your question about how to add Punjabi language features to LibreOffice is answered in great detail in the illustrated document [LibreOffice Getting Started Guide](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/a/af/GS40-GettingStartedLO.odt). This document contains a complete description of everything you need to do to add a language to LibreOffice on page 55, including how to:

- Install the required dictionaries
- Change some locale and language settings
- Choose spelling options

Comment: @Karel.. thank you for your article. Its works. This is to be so simply & well described format Its take just one minute to resolve my problem. So Thanks again.